# How to disable the "intelligent" features in the web Outlook editor

Tags: outlook.com

In web Outlook (outlook.office.com) I have all of the Microsoft Editor features toggled off but there's still some vestigial "intelligence" getting in my way and I would really like to give it the *coup de grâce*. How is that done?

For example, if I want to type

```
            ten (10) of the subjects could not decide whether premature optimization
            or clever labor-saving features were the root of all evil.
```

when I get this far in my typing

```
           ten (10)
```

the editor proceeds to create a numbered list.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this automatic formatting cannot be properly disabled in the web version of Outlook. Switching to plaintext mode stops it, but you lose all other formatting options in the process.

[image: How to switch to plaintext formatting]

If you want, plaintext formatting can be set as default in Settings -> All Outlook Settings -> Mail -> Compose and Reply